# Network location provider does not work on ICS(Huawei )

Tags: android, geolocation

I have new Huawei handset Ascend G330D with 4.0.4 on board.
The prob is that "network" location provider does not work and does not return any coordinates at all.

The other facts are
1. App is correct- it works on quite a few android devices
2. gps location provider works ok
3. Google Maps app works perfectly even with network location (ie without gps)! (I have replaced NetworkLocation.apk in /system/app, after that Google apps (Maps, Local) started working with network location, initially they did not work neither)
4. No any 3rd party apps (from Market) work with network location as well

As Maps is not open source and I cannot see that's the difference with app which use Google API, but I guess that Google Maps just may use another source of geolocation (or authorization keys)...

Does anyone have any ideas where to dig to get network location working?

Comment: The question is not related to location provider usage, but specific device(or fw). My program works ok, other programs(except google ones) do not work neither. I have checked from debugger- network provider is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this Tutorial for complete example

[**Get Current Location coordinates , City name**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html)

Also Here is my working code which is working with both

- GPS Provider
- Network Provider

  ```
  public class MyLocationListener extends Service implements LocationListener {

  private static final String TAG = "MyLocationListener";

  private Context context = null;

  private Location location = null;
  private LocationManager locationManager = null;

  public static boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
  boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
  boolean canGetLocation = false;

  public double latitude = 0.0;
  public double longitude = 0.0;
  public String location_address = null;

  // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
  private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
  // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
  private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

  public MyLocationListener(Context ctx) {
      Log.v(TAG + ".MyLocationListener",
              "MyLocationListener constructor called");
      this.context = ctx;
      getLocationValue();
  }

  public Location getLocationValue() {
      Log.v(TAG + ".getLocationValue", "getLocationValue method called");

      try {
          locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                  .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

          isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                  .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

          isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                  .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

          if (isGPSEnabled) {

              this.canGetLocation = true;
              Log.v(TAG + ".getLocationValue", "GPS provider enabled");
              // Toast.makeText(context, "Gps", 1).show();
              if (location == null) {
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                          MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                  if (locationManager != null) {
                      location = locationManager
                              .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                      if (location != null) {
                          latitude = location.getLatitude();
                          longitude = location.getLongitude();
                          Log.v(TAG, "Gps Co-ordinates are:" + latitude + " "
                                  + longitude);

                      }
                  }
              }

          } else if (isNetworkEnabled) {

              // Toast.makeText(context, "Net", 1).show();
              Log.v(TAG + ".getLocationValue", "Network provider enabled");
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                      LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                      MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

              if (locationManager != null) {
                  location = locationManager
                          .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                  if (location != null) {
                      latitude = location.getLatitude();
                      longitude = location.getLongitude();
                      Log.v(TAG, "Co-ordinates are: " + latitude + " "
                              + longitude);

                  }
              }

          } else {
              showSettingsAlert();
          }

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return location;
  }

  /**
   * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
   * app
   * */
  public void stopUsingGPS() {
      if (locationManager != null) {
          locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocationListener.this);
      }
  }

  public double getLatitude() {
      if (location != null) {
          latitude = location.getLatitude();
      }
      return latitude;
  }

  public double getLongitude() {
      if (location != null) {
          longitude = location.getLongitude();
      }
      return longitude;
  }

  /**
   * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
   * 
   * @return boolean
   * */
  public boolean canGetLocation() {
      return this.canGetLocation;
  }

  /**
   * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
   * lauch Settings Options
   * */
  public void showSettingsAlert() {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

      alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
      alertDialog
              .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

      alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(
                              Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                      context.startActivity(intent);
                  }
              });
      alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                  }
              });
      alertDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }}
  ```

use above code this way, whenever you want in any Activity

```
MyLocationListener mylistner = new MyLocationListener(context);
        double lat = mylistner.latitude;
        double lon = mylistner.longitude;
```

**Note**: also I have blow permissions in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```